# Make CentOS 6.x a port forwarding NAT device

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, routing, nat

I would like to make CentOS a port forwarding NAT machine using iptables. This is the first time I've tried this and I think i might need a little help.

This is the configuration i'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to make a remote desktop connection through the CentOS machine on port 5500 and have CentOS connect to the server on port 3389.

[image]

192.168.21.11 is the client that should connect to port 3389 on 192.168.9.120 by connecting to 192.168.21.10 (CentOS) on port 5500.

- CentOS eth0 is 192.168.9.20/24
- CentOS eth1 is 192.168.21.10/24

What I tried so far:

1. Disabled SELINUX
2. Enabled IPv4 forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf

   ```
   /etc/sysctl.conf
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
   ```
3. Ran the following iptables commands

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.21.10 --dport 5500 -j DNAT --to 192.168.9.120:3389
   iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 5500 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 5500 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   service iptables save
   ```

After saving this configuration I was not able to make the remote desktop connection I'm trying to achieve, so is there anything wrong with my iptables rules? Or is there something I might be missing?

Comment: And where is the QUESTION?

Comment: Edited to add a question.

Comment: So it's not working :)

Comment: http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-sg-en-4/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this rule to your /etc/sysconfig/iptables right after `-A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.21.10 --dport 5500 -j DNAT --to 192.168.9.120:3389`

`-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.9.120 -j MASQUERADE`

Second check if net.ipv4.ip_forward is set to 1 by executing
'sysctl -a | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward`

If it's still set up on 0 then execute:

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: Ah needed the masquerade :) `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.9.120 -j MASQUERADE` worked. Also `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: -I is better than -A in most cases and especially when you don't know the full ruleset.

Answer (score 0):

You should [read up](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) on the difference between `iptables -A` and `iptables -I` and take a look at the default rules on your system. It seems fairly likely that your INPUT rule at least will not work because of the difference.

Setting a value in /etc/sysctl.conf does not set it in the running kernel. The [sysctl(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) man page is your friend.

Don't just disable SELinux - it's there to help protect you.